# function of `with` in `concurrent.futures`

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

The code below executes as expected by returning the total finish time as almost zero because it doesn't wait for the threads to finish every job.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

start = time.perf_counter()


def do_something(seconds):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'Done Sleeping...{seconds}'



executor= concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
secs = [10, 4, 3, 2, 1]

fs = [executor.submit(do_something, sec) for sec in secs]


finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

But with the `with` command it does wait:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    secs = [10, 4, 3, 2, 1]

    fs = [executor.submit(do_something, sec) for sec in secs]
```

Why? What is the reason that `with` has this behavior with multithreading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `concurrent.futures.Executor` in a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is equivalent to calling `Executor.shutdown` after using it – causing the executor to wait for all tasks to complete. An `Executor` used in a `with` guarantees proper shutdown of concurrent tasks even if an error occurs inside the `with` block.

> #### [**Executor.shutdown**(*wait=True*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown)
>
> Signal the executor that it should free any
>   resources that it is using when the currently pending futures are done
>   executing. Calls to `Executor.submit()` and `Executor.map()` made after
>   shutdown will raise `RuntimeError`.
>
> [...]
>
> You can avoid having to call this method explicitly if you use the
>   `with` statement, which will shutdown the `Executor` (waiting as if
>   `Executor.shutdown()` were called with *wait* set to `True`):
>   [...]

Answer (score 4):

`concurrent.futures` is not well documented. When you create an executor it must be shutdown to terminate its threads or processes. That code will signal the threads to exit by pushing a `None` command to them and then wait for them to complete. In your first case, had you added `executor.shutdown()` you'd see the delay. It was there anyway - the program still took 10 seconds to exit.

The executor can be used as a context manager (it as `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods). When it exits the "with" block, `__exit__` is called and it in turn does the `shutdown` call for you.